# write to root wheel directory

Tags: python, file-permissions, osx-el-capitan

I might be missing something, but I have a directory root:wheel (755), and when I do a

```
sudo touch a
```

it says

```
touch: a: Operation not permitted
```

Doesn't sudo give me full access regardless of who I am when I run that sudo?

**Update:**
It sounds like the issue is that I am doing this in the /System directory on El Capitan, which is locked down by El Capitan, so instructions like this:

https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/installing_python_osx/

which attempt to put new python installed versions in the same directory as the default versions will not work unless I disable the [rootless](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) feature.

And yet I cannot find anyone postings about trying to do the same.
Any other suggestions other than running everything with 'python3' or is that how everyone does it?

Comment: I believe you need to be the file owner to change the access time.

Comment: the file 'a' doesn't exist.

Comment: System Integrity Protection?